# pulling data frames from a global dictionary (long script)

Tags: python, dataframe, montecarlo

WARNING: Long post. I did my best to break it up into something digestible so by the grace of god someone may help me.

So cool cats of stack, Check it out, I am building out an efficient frontier tool for portfolio analysis. I have the tool working just fine by calling data directly from excel files (df = pd.read_csv(foo.csv)). However, now that I have hundreds of excel files, Probably soon to be thousands, I would like to load them once into a dictionary which over hundreds of thousands of iterations will save real time.

I wrote a quick function (below) to load the data into a global dictionary. The dictionary seems to work perfectly.

```
equityLibrary = {}

def listFiles(path):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        return[path]
    else:
        files = []
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            files += listFiles(path + '/' + filename)
        return files

def loadData():
    ##This function jsut lists the files in my data dir
    library = listFiles('./data')
    
    for stock in library:
        startKeyName = stock[7:]
        keyName = startKeyName[:-4]
        variableName = keyName.lower()
        df = readData(keyName)
        equityLibrary[variableName] = df
```

ok, cool. Dataframes are loaded into a global dictionary. Now, Lets get the necessary portfolio Data, I'm compiling the volatility and return of a portfolio of stocks with the below functions:

```
def PortfolioVolAndReturn(holdings, weights):
    table = pd.DataFrame()
    weights = np.array(weights)

    for i in holdings:
        df = equityLibrary[i.lower()]
        table[i] = df.close

    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

    ##Convert to log return eventually
    dailyReturns = table.pct_change()
    annualReturn = dailyReturns.mean() * 252

    dailyCOVAR = dailyReturns.cov()
    annualCOVAR = dailyCOVAR * 252

    returnOut = np.dot(weights, annualReturn)
    volOut = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(annualCOVAR, weights)))
    
    return returnOut, volOut


##Return Sharp ratio
def sharpeRatio(vol, returns):
    return returns/vol
```

That works!! ... but only once. Here's the core issue: when I run this in a monte carlo simulation, the dataFrame that I return has one correct row and all of the others return with NaN values across all columns. I am using this function to run the simulation:

```
##takes in number of simulations for 
def runSim(holdings, simulations):
    weightsArray = []
    returnsArray = []
    volArray = []

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i in range(simulations):
        weights = np.random.rand(len(holdings))
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        returns, vol = PortfolioVolAndReturn(holdings, weights)

        weightsArray.append(weights)
        returnsArray.append(returns)
        volArray.append(vol)
    
    df['weights'] = weightsArray
    df['return'] = returnsArray
    df['vol'] = volArray

    return df
```

My return is broken:

```
                                              weights    return      vol
0   [0.047066195990327415, 0.27999255422401625, 0....  0.269764  0.35462
1   [0.6172192455260814, 0.08842975803644981, 0.29...       NaN      NaN
2   [0.3610819481882519, 0.5059521988331586, 0.132...       NaN      NaN
3   [0.01626716037860542, 0.16093554050483386, 0.8...       NaN      NaN
```

I KNOW that the issue is with the global dictionary. If I call the dataframes directly from the csv files its fine but super slow. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my dictionary feeds nonsense after a second call. what am I doing wrong and why am I not smart enough to figure it out??

UPDATE:
the issue is in Function PortfolioVolAndReturn. No matter how long or short the holding arguement is, the last column appends to the data frame as NaN. Examples:

```
       CSCO   INTC  CAT
0     26.84  34.23  NaN
1     26.52  34.47  NaN
2     26.15  34.19  NaN
```

and

```
      CSCO   INTC     CAT  JPM
0     26.84  34.23   69.24  NaN
1     26.52  34.47   69.22  NaN
2     26.15  34.19   68.25  NaN
```

That makes absolutely no sense to me. running through the code I have no idea what would cause that. Am I not iterating correctly through a dictionary? I feel like everything is logical and the dataFrames shouldn't be pulled incorrectly. O_o

Comment: There is nothing immediate jumping out to me in the code. Without data it's hard to say, my guess is that the error is in `PortfolioVolAndReturn` and is probably a result of `nan` values in your data causing havoc with your dot products.  I would recommend looking into Dask.DataFrame as well for loading your data, it will probably make a lot of this easier and faster. Note even a single `nan` in any of your vectors will result in a `nan` output when performing dot products.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for coming back so fast. So, after spending the morning printing each line, you called it, the error is in PortfolioVolAndReturn. The last column only appends to the dataFrame as NaN no matter How many equities I cover. I'm updating the Main question to reflect the issue. Will also check out Dask. I'm relatively new to coding so if you could give me the 10 word How it helps I'd really appreciate it!!

Comment: Dask is a distributed build of the basic python data science environment. (pandas, numpy, a little sklearn). Dask.DataFrame utilizes lazy dataframes and has a very similiar syntax to pandas. For your use case, Dask can lazy (and in parallel) load multiple files into a single dataframe in one line of code by simply adding a `*` to the unique aspects of the file paths. By doing this, you get all the power of pandas but faster on large datasets, thus you could handle the majority of the transformations with basic commands and `apply` functions. Code could be 1/3 a long.

Comment: That's awesome. checking it out. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after taking a break and coming back I got everything running pretty smooth using another function call:

```
def closingPriceTable(holdings):
    table = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in holdings:
        df = equityLibrary[i.lower()]
        table[i] = df.close
    
    return table
```

Still don't know why my original calls didn't work. Really wouldn't mind someone looking and letting me know what dumb thing I did.